# How to add constraints to a spline?

Tags: constraints, spline

I am using the `geomdl` python library to build 3D splines, either by fitting a set of points, with underlaying `NURBS` or `B-splines`, or directly `NURBS`. I need to add constraints. For example, between two control points, I want the spline to fit in a 2D plane I define.

One approach would be to cut the control points list in parts to isolate parts with constraints and then to join the splines. That's *divide and conquer*. In my example, in the constrained plane, I could use a 2D spline here.

Another approach would be the following, which is only a heuristic and could provide bad results:

1. Compute a first 3D *fitting* spline
2. Sample the result
3. Check if points don't satisfy the constraints
4. If there are points not satisfying the constraints:

   4.1. Move the *k* first & *k* last points inside the constraints for each non compliant segment, *k* being the spline degree

   4.2. Rebuild the control points list from the original one plus these new points

   4.3. Compute the spline again

   4.4. GOTO 2

The idea of this heuristic, in the case of the 2D plane constraint, is that if for a segment of the control points, *k* first and last ones are in the plane, along with the control points between, all the points between should be also in the plane.

Questions:

- What is the math for splines with constraints or wayforward, independently of the python library I use? I have found this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220564437_Optimal_smoothing_and_interpolating_splines_with_constraints), but too much theoric for what I can do by myself
- If the right method is divide and conquer, what is the math to join the splines? I am sure there are some pitfalls. Is *k* last control points of the first spline and *k* first points of the next one identical correct?
- Can `geomdl` perform it, possibly with some hack? Or another library?

Comment: What do you mean by "fit in a 2D plane" ??

Comment: I mean constrained in a 2D plane. In my use case, the whole spline is 3D, but three sub-parts shall be constrained in three different planes

Comment: I guess that with enough control points in these planes, a B-spline will do.

Comment: Yves, I don't have these additional control points and I want the spline algorithm to do its job. That's why I would prefer an algorithm which take into account such constraints

Comment: I suppose this is a math question but I think you may actually have as much luck with it on SO

Comment: If you don't have enough control points in the plane it is impossible to constrain the curve to stay there.

Comment: @Alexander I think both are legitimate since they seek for different purposes. I have posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674584/how-to-add-boundary-constraints-to-a-spline-with-geomdl-or-other-library)